# Sitecore publishes item when saved

Tags: publishing

I already disabled the scheduled publish in sitecore using a patch file. the config is now:

```
<agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.PublishAgent" method="Run" interval="00:00:00" patch:source="PublishAgentInterval.config">
<param desc="source database">master</param>
<param desc="target database">web</param>
<param desc="mode (full or smart or incremental)" patch:source="PublishAgentInterval.config">smart</param>
<param desc="languages">en, da</param>
</agent>
```

However, when i save an item, it still publishes the item. any ideas why this is occuring? this is in production environment but in staging it doesn't happen. both have the same patch file with this value:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/" xmlns:env="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/env/">
    <sitecore>
        <scheduling>
            <agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.PublishAgent" method="Run" interval="00:00:00">
                <patch:attribute name="interval" value="00:00:00"/>
                
                <param desc="mode (full or smart or incremental)">smart</param>
            </agent>
        </scheduling>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

This is the config for item:saved event:

```
<event name="item:saved" patch:source="XSitecore.Audit.Config">
<handler type="Sitecore.Links.ItemEventHandler, Sitecore.Kernel" method="OnItemSaved"/>
<handler type="Sitecore.Globalization.ItemEventHandler, Sitecore.Kernel" method="OnItemSaved"/>
<handler type="Sitecore.Rules.ItemEventHandler, Sitecore.Kernel" method="OnItemSaved"/>
<handler type="Sitecore.Caching.Placeholders.PlaceholderCacheEventHandler, Sitecore.Kernel" method="UpdateCaches" resolve="true"/>
<handler type="Sitecore.Marketing.xMgmt.Definitions.ItemEventHandler, Sitecore.Marketing.xMgmt" method="OnItemSaved" patch:source="Sitecore.Marketing.config"/>
<handler type="Sitecore.Analytics.Data.ItemEventHandler, Sitecore.Analytics" method="OnItemSaved" patch:source="Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config"/>
<handler type="Sitecore.ContentTesting.Events.GenerateScreenshot, Sitecore.ContentTesting" method="OnItemSaved" patch:source="Sitecore.ContentTesting.PreemptiveScreenshot.config">
<excludeFields hint="list:ExcludeFieldFromComparison">
<created>__created</created>
<createdby>__created by</createdby>
<updated>__updated</updated>
<updatedby>__updated by</updatedby>
<revision>__revision</revision>
<sortorder>__sortorder</sortorder>
<validfrom>__valid from</validfrom>
<workflow>__workflow</workflow>
<workflowstate>__workflow state</workflowstate>
<lock>__lock</lock>
<pageleveltestsetdefinition>__Page Level Test Set Definition</pageleveltestsetdefinition>
</excludeFields>
</handler>
<handler type="Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.Deployment.Events.SegmentDeployedEventHandler, Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client" method="OnItemSaved" patch:source="Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.config">
<param type="Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.Deployment.DeploySegmentDefinitionProcessor, Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client">
<param ref="experienceAnalytics/client/logger"/>
<param type="Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core.Repositories.ReferenceData.ReferenceDataSegmentStore, Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core"/>
</param>
</handler>
<handler type="XSitecore.Wcms.CwpBase.XSitecore.Wcms.Audit.ItemAudit.ItemOperations,XSitecore.Wcms" method="OnItemSaved" patch:source="XSitecore.Audit.Config"/>
</event>
```

Comment: Probably a workflow

Comment: Maybe a workflow or any save event?

Comment: @MarkCassidy i also tested an item without a workflow and after i saved it, it still gets published. any config that might be the cause?

Comment: @GauravAgarwal tested an item without a workflow and it still gets published after i save the item. this one only happens in production which is strange

Comment: I know asking this is silly but can you please confirm you are saving thing in master DB not in Web? If master then check showconfig and search is there any save event that is causing this.

Comment: @GauravAgarwal i updated the question showing item:saved event

Comment: For clarification, when you say "published", how are you validating that it is published? Are you specifically switching to the web db and checking it exists in the web db? Or are you looking at the live site? If the second, it could be you have your site in "live mode" where the website is pulling from master

Comment: hi @JasonSt-Cyr. i check in Web db.

Comment: Can you please check the configuration using ShowConfig and find "Sitecore.Pipelines.Save.Save" with any custom processor?

Comment: @AmitKumar in showconfig it says `<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.Save.Save, Sitecore.Kernel" mode="on"/>`

Comment: It's default setting. Any scheduled task with "<event name="item:saved">"?

Comment: @AmitKumar the one with `<event name="item:saved">` i have is in the post above

Comment: Any scheduled task mentioned as child attribute under this tag which may be custom implementation.

Comment: Maybe there is a rule defined to publish when the item is saved? check here: /sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Item Saved

Comment: If the item is indeed publishing, then you will see records in the publishing.log file. Please review that file immediately after saving the item. My suspicion is that your CM instance is targeting the web database and there is no publish at all. If it is indeed publishing, then I recommend tapping into a publish pipeline and logging data. Additionally, you can set your publishing log to DEBUG value which is the most verbose log level.

Comment: @katho2404 i already checked, it contains Rules and Tags item. in rules theres no descendants while in Tags there is default item. nothing fancy, i think these are default items

Comment: @jrap already checked but no logs of it. the field i am testing is a Rich Text Full type. any way i can set publishing log to DEBUG value?

Comment: @AmitKumar it's the same value in our staging environment, which is owned by the hosting provider so i think it's okay

Comment: Google Sitecore log level, you can target publishing log. But I highly suspect a configuration issue. Either your shell site is targeting web, your connection strings are both web, your <database> node is incorrect, etc. I would look through your ShowConfig and search for both “master” and “web” and verify it all lines up properly.

Comment: @jrap got it, will search for these keywords

Comment: @jrap is it under `<sites>` node?

Comment: hi all, it seems clearing the EventQueue and PublishQueue seems to fixed it. This is the link: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/clean-up-the-eventqueue-and-publishqueue-tables.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearing the EventQueue and PublishQueue tables seems to have fixed it. I tested items and it doesn't go to Web DB anymore. This is the link on how to clear the tables: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/clean-up-the-eventqueue-and-publishqueue-tables.html